# If $X$ is geometric with parameter $p$, find the probability that $X$ is even?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

[Find the probability that a geometric random variable $X$ is an even number](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1014250/find-the-probability-that-a-geometric-random-variable-x-is-an-even-number)

I was reading this old question and wanted to solve it when I noticed something. The approach below seems to give a wrong answer when it should not(?).

Let $E$ denote that event that $X$ is even:

$$P(E)=P(E|X>2)P(X>2)+P(E|X\leq 2)P(X \leq 2)$$
$$P(E)=P(E)(1-p-(1-p)p)+(1-p)(p+(1-p)p)$$
$$P(E)(1-(1-p-(1-p)p)=(1-p)(p+(1-p)p)$$
$$P(E)=1-p$$

So $P(E)=1-p$, but this is wrong. What is the flaw here?

Comment: How are you computing, e.g., $P(E\,|\,X>2)$?  Seems to me that, if you can do that, you are essentially done.

Comment: So what you are saying is that $P(E|X>2)=P(E)$ is wrong? Because that is what I used in the calculation and obviously I get wrong answer

Comment: Ah, I understand.  In that case, you computed $P(X>2)$ incorrectly.  It;s just $(1-p)^2$.  Similarly, $P(E\cap (X≤2))=p(1-p)$.

Comment: Indeed. $X>2$ exactly when the first two trials fail.

Comment: @lulu yes I see now that I computed $P(E|X \leq 2)P(X \leq 2)$ wrongly. Thank you.